# csv.writer exports horizontally

Tags: python

I have a list filled with values. I want to export the list to a .csv file.
I want the values to be on top of each other, yet right now they get exported next to each other.

e.g. I want it to be like:

```
1
2
3
```

not
`1 2 3`

How do I have to change my code?

```
with open('C:(...)file.csv', "w", newline='\n') as csfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csfile, delimiter =';')
    wr.writerow([item[0] for item in sntlst])
```

It is important to receive `item[0]` of my list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `delimiter` argument to `'\n'`:

```
with open('C:(...)file.csv', "w", newline='\n') as csfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csfile, delimiter='\n')
    wr.writerow([item[0] for item in sntlst])
```

The `newline='\n'` isn't even necessary, so you can do without it:

```
with open('C:(...)file.csv', "w") as csfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csfile, delimiter='\n')
    wr.writerow([item[0] for item in sntlst])
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you have accepted (by @Ann Zen) may work, but that's due to a fluke because technically it's abusing the use of `delimiter` keyword argument with respect to the sample shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) of opening files for a `csv.writer` — and because of that it might now work properly on all platforms.

So, that said, in my opinion the code shown below would be a proper and better way to do things. It makes each item in your list a "row" of one item in the CSV file that's being created.

```
import csv

sntlst = [1, 2, 3]
output_file_path = 'list_file.csv'

with open(output_file_path, "w", newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerows([item] for item in sntlst)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate the effort. Sadly, after trying your Code, I got an error for my specific case. (I/O)

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough information—"I got an error"—for me to debug the problem. There's not much going on, so it's probably something simple…